# Required attribute and type email dows not work. ReactJS and Materia UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I'm new in ReactJS and Material-UI and I'm trying to build a normal form just for fun, but some attributes does not work and I really can't understand why

Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import InputAdornment from '@material-ui/core/InputAdornment';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import AccountCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import LockIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Lock';
import EmailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Email';
import PaymentIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Payment';
import TodayIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Today';
import moduleName from '@material-ui/core/';

export class FormOpzioniPagamento extends Component {

    continue = e =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.nextStep();
    };
    render() {
        const {values,handleChange}=this.props;
        return (
            <div align="center">
            <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="https://i1.rgstatic.net/ii/profile.image/363082749628419-1463577081575_Q512/Rosario_Sorbello2.jpg" align="center"/>
            <FormControl>
            <FormControl required>
                <InputLabel htmlFor="input-with-icon-adornment" color="secondary">Nome</InputLabel>
                <Input
                required
                id="input-with-icon-adornment"
                color="secondary"
                startAdornment={
                    <InputAdornment position="start">
                    <AccountCircle />
                    </InputAdornment>
                }
                onChange={handleChange('nome')}
                /></FormControl>
               </div>
export default FormOpzioniPagamento
```

It just allows me to continue without any problem

Comment: 'Doesn't work' is not enough to describe the problem. You should provide code you use, tell us your expectations and tell what you really get in term of data you see on the page or in console

Comment: I press continue and does not shows any error message. I just want a popup message like HTML5 normal

Answer (score 0):

the code you have provide that is buggy code. Please try this example:

```
import InputAdornment from '@material-ui/core/InputAdornment';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import AccountCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import LockIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Lock';
import EmailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Email';
import PaymentIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Payment';
import TodayIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Today';
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

export default class FormExample extends React.Component {

    nextStep = () => {
        alert('nextStep is called');
    };
    handleChange = (message) => {
        alert('handleChange is called. The parameter is: ' + message);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <FormOpzioniPagamento nextStep={this.nextStep} handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class FormOpzioniPagamento extends React.Component {

    continue = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.nextStep();
    };

    render() {
        const {values, handleChange} = this.props;
        return (
            <div align="center">
                <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp"
                        src="https://i1.rgstatic.net/ii/profile.image/363082749628419-1463577081575_Q512/Rosario_Sorbello2.jpg"
                        align="center"/>
                <FormControl required>
                    <InputLabel htmlFor="input-with-icon-adornment" color="secondary">Nome</InputLabel>
                    <Input
                        required
                        id="input-with-icon-adornment"
                        color="secondary"
                        startAdornment={
                            <InputAdornment position="start">
                                <AccountCircle/>
                            </InputAdornment>
                        }
                        onChange={handleChange('nome')}
                    />
                    <Button color={"primary"} onClick={()=>{handleChange('submit') }}>Submit</Button>
                </FormControl>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

[Here is the Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-noyce-85hi4)